# WCF service fires event itself

Tags: c#, wcf, events, wcf-client

Is it possible to fire event from service to connected clients without request from client? (I know, if I use client request I could use callback)

I store object in the service with some actual state. State of this object can change very often. 
First method: I can send request to this service every second, but I suppose they are better ways.

I thought about event called by wcfservice itself - possible?

Comment: Take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1006058/941243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are callback available in WCF, I guess that what you are asking for.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx

Comment: Isn't it CALL-BACK? And in this case there's no CALL

Comment: @Saint you might be taking the "callback" name a little too literally. As long as you keep a collection of subscribers (i.e. your clients) you can always make calls to them, even without them initiating the call. This is a way you'd tackle asynchronous services. You can force your clients to "initiate" a session ( http://www.remondo.net/managing-wcf-session-lifetime-isinitiating-isterminating/ ) that way you have a single method that you can use to keep add subscribers to a collection from. Then, whenever you want to broadcast, just iterate through that subscriber collection.